# Select multiple not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I've a select with multiple attribute in my AngularJS project. It get its data from my controler as you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sylla/zb8Aq).

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="object" ng-options="obj.name for obj in List"></select>
    {{object}}
</div>
```

Controler:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.List = [
                {"id": 1,
                 "name": "name1"},
                {"id": 2,
                 "name": "name2"},
                {"id": 3,
                 "name": "name3"}
               ]
}
```

Everything is working in the jsFiddle but it's not the case in my project: I've a click problem. When I try to select an option, sometimes the click just don't do anything... To show you what my problem is, I've made [a little video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lVrggTFUqg) of my screen.

I've searched on the Internet about my problem, found [this topic](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2113) but it doesn't solve anything. I've tried with Angular 1.1.5 and 1.2.0-rc.2 and with Firefox 24.0 and Chromium 28.0.1500.71. I using Ubuntu 13.04.

Do you have a idea of what can do this or maybe an alternative? Thanks in advance!

Comment: But we can't see your code and wether you are pressing a ctrl button or not.

Comment: I'm never pressing CTRL button and my code is just that!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same: Everyting looks fine (no errors, etc), but clicking the multiple select didn't do anything.

I was using AngularJS 1.2.13.
Upgrading to 1.2.19 did solve the issue.